# Opel Corsa lite 1.4 2002

Tags: fuel-consumption, opel

After reconditioning cylinder head and skimming.  Fitting new hydraulic lifters and rockers, find no compression on engine once oil reaches the lifters compression disappears.  Tried reducing length of valves and even using gaskets on cambelt.  Little or no improvement.  Compression on 2 cylinders.  3 & 4

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're getting at here, especially when you say, "... *Tried reducing length of valves and even using gaskets on cambelt.* ..." This really doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: You should probably do a leak down test to see why the cylinder has no compression.

Comment: @raymond  Can you have a look at your question and clarify it?  It needs more information and your words are broken up quite a bit.  I'd like to see it get answered but in it's current state it's very confusing.